# Replacement for big switch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns

I have a page named "ReportController.aspx" whose purpose is to instantiate a report (class) based on query string parameters

```
        switch (Request.QueryString["Report"])
        {                
            case "ReportA":
                CreateReportAReport("ReportA's Title");
                break;
            case "ReportB":
                CreateReportBReport("ReportB's Title");
                break;                
            case "ReportC":
                CreateReportCReport("ReportC's Title");
                break;
            case "ReportD":
                CreateReportDReport("ReportD's Title");
                break;
                ...
```

Basically, each time a new report is needed there will be this overhead of adding a case and adding a method.  This switch statement could get very very long.  I read that is is possible to use a Dictionary to map a Report to ?.  How would this look using a Dictionary (assuming this is a better way).

Also, `CreateReportXReport` method basically passes a bunch of additional QueryString values to the report class's constructor (each report class has a different constructor).

Comment: you could consider using a database to store the values and write a query that gets what you need.  Then all you have to do is insert data with each new report.

Comment: @northpole - Not sure if I understand.  The values are based on user selections from pages that called to ReportController.

Comment: refer to Patrick Karcher's response.  Basically, you still need to manage the user selection, however, you put the mapping to the selection in the database.  So you have one method that responds to a type.  The method collects what it needs from the DB (what type of report it is and what that report needs to be built) and builds the report accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that all reports implement `IReport`, you can do it using `Func<IReport>`, like this:

```
IDictionary<string,Func<IReport>> dictToReport = new Dictionary {
    {"ReportA", () => CreateReportAReport("ReportA's Title") }
,   {"ReportB", () => CreateReportBReport("ReportB's Title") }
,   ...
};
```

You can then replace the switch with this code:

```
var myReport = dictToReport[Request.QueryString["Report"]]();
```

Comment: Then you'd still have to add an item to the dictionary for each new report - conceptually it's the same.

Comment: @BrokenGlass It is not really the same in terms of maintenance, because you can reuse the same `IDictionary` as many times as you would like without copy-pasting the code. You cannot do the same thing with the `switch` statement. You can isolate the switch in a method that you share, but it is not as flexible. I do agree that this is not a fix-it-all solution for factories, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Are you hinting that a factory method pattern would be even better than this?

Comment: @subt13 This is just one way of implementing a factory (if you put a static method around the `dictToReport[Request.QueryString["Report"]]()` call, it would become a *factory method*, but you do not *have* to do it if you do not see a design reason for it). The tricky issue is eliminating `CreateReportXYZReport` methods, because they must produce constructor parameters "from the thin air", and the parameters are of different structure.

Comment: There are a lot of great answers, some I do not understand yet.  However, you gave the answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 6):

There's no getting around having to type in the new information somewhere; the key is to get it out of the code, to avoid recompiling and redeploying for such a trivial change.

Some good options are to list these value in an XML config file, or better yet, your database.

You'll probably want to fill out a dictionary with this data, whatever the source.  This will:

- Make it easy to cache
- Make for clean, fast code

When the time comes to pull your data out of configuration into code, you'd add items to the dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<string, IReportCreator> = configDataGetter.GetReportDataFromDB().
    ToDictionary(r => r.Name, myReportCreatorFactory(r => r.ReportID))
```

This example assumes your getting data as entity object of some kind, and using a factory that would use a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for your code that creates reports.  There's a bagillion ways your could be doing this of course.

I assume the reports are just too extensive, varied, and different in nature that you can't just put sql and styling building block in the db?

**Edit** based on op's comments:

Ah, gotcha.  Well, I don't know how much time you have, but as much as you push everything into some sort of [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), you have better options you'll later.  I'm going to give you some thoughts that will hopefully help, from similar things I've done.  Each step is an improvement in itself, but also a baby step to really separating your report logic from this shell code.  Further, I can see you already know what you're doing and I'm sure know some of what I'll say below, but I don't know what you know, and it will be helpful for others.

First, pull out any and every bit of information from code to db (if you haven't already), and you'll add more db fields (and a table or two) as you improve your setup.

You might know about it already, but I'll mention it for others, to check out the strategy pattern I reference above.  You can have the custom logic of each "report function" actually be in the constructor of your various strategy classes.  They would all inherit from your base ReportGenerator (or sport a common IReportGenerator interface).  They can and should share the same constructor; varying report parameters would be handled by a parameter of type dictionary.  Each class's constructor implementation would know the types of the variables is needs (from db configuration), and would cast/use them accordingly.

Next step might be to really get rid of your select statement in your factory, using [reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial).  You'd have to have the name of the class as part of your reports configuration data in the db (and have a common constructor).

At this point, the way to add a new report is pretty clean, even though you've got to add a new class each time.  That good.  It fulfills the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [open-closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principals.

Now, there's just the final step of **removing the classes from your app**, so they can be added/edited on the fly.  Check out [MEF](http://managed%20extensibility%20framework).  This is what it's made for.  Some things you might find on the internet that you probably **shouldn't** use are [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) (great when there was nothing else, but MEF is better) and the compilation-as-a-service features coming in .NET 5.  MEF is the way to go.

Comment: Right.  For java, this is why you'll see things like the Spring Framework.  This way you can just reference a common factory object or dictionary.  Your code just calls ReportFactory.create(Request.QueryString["Report"]), and the logic there is maintained outside of your class, making it less complex.

Comment: @PatrickKarcher - Each report class takes in a list of parameters in its constructor (not shown above).  I'd still have to deploy the new file (report) to the server, the parameters and report names are just one part of it.  There's an entire new class involved.

Comment: @PatrickKarcher - Maybe in the future I will implement this way, but I just don't understand how yet.

Comment: @PatrickKarcher - If stackoverflow allowed me to upvote you again, I would.  :P.  Strategy pattern's definition seems to fit for this.

Comment: @PatrickKarcher - I didn't think of using MEF in regular ASP.NET Web Forms application.  I played with it for the small Silverlight portion of my site.  Metaphorically, you are saying that each report class would be a module and discoverable for MEF to be loaded (in which case your XML configuration statement would def. work)

Comment: "I assume the reports are just too extensive, varied, and different in nature that you can't just put sql and styling building block in the db?"  Yes, exactly right.

Comment: @subt13.  Right, each report would be separately discoverable.  Now, whether you *should* go that far I have no idea.  That ties in with how often you'll really be adding/editing them, how often you'd otherwise be deploying anyway, the patience of the customer, how difficult it is to deploy, how much MEF would *otherwise* be useful to you (such that time spent on it could be considered a little R&D), etc.  The key point is that even if you don't go that far, moving things it that direction is good, and usually has benefits later we can't guess now.

Answer (score 1):

I think is better re-design this code and convert it into some database table ("Reports") to keep there the list of reports and ID of each report.

That's it.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I'd still have to switch on the report after reading it from the database, in order to pass the appropriate user selections from the querystring to the report class.  I don't see how this would be better.

Comment: @subt13 It's ok totally. You can try to use Session / Cache to keep there any Dictionary you need. So add to the session code  this Dictionary with list of reports once only.

Comment: You are probably right, I guess I don't understand enough yet to implement it.

Comment: May be you have to read more about how to implement ASP .NET Session Manager? Just Google it...

Comment: I have session turned off in web config.  I understand session.  I think you are suggesting I move storage of report information to a data store, rather than a page.  I would have to see an example of this to fully understand what I could gain.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a `Dictionary<string, string>` you would simply build one up as a static cache in the containing type

```
public class Container {
  private static Dictionary<string, Func<Report>> ReportMap = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<Report>>();
  static Container() {
    ReportMap["ReportA"] = () => CreateReportAReport("ReportA's Title");
    ReportMap["ReportB"] = () => CreateReportBReport("ReportB's Title");
    // etc ...
  }
}
```

Now that the map is built you simply do a lookup in the function instead of a `switch`

```
Func<Report> func;
if (!ReportMap.TryGetValue(Request.QueryString["Report"), out func)) {
  // Handle it not being present
  throw new Exception(..);
}

Report report = func();
```