# Infragistics UltraWinGrid column-level CellChange event handler

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is there a way to define a specific CellChange event handler for each column of a UltraWinGrid?

I'm refactoring a CellChange event handler for an Infragistics UltraWinGrid that looks like this:

```
Select Case e.Cell.Column.Key

Case "Name"
' handle cell change event for Name cell with a big ugly blob of code

Case "Title"
' handle cell change event for Title cell with a big ugly blob of code

' ... etc ...

End Select
```

I'd like to be able to create event handlers that fire when a cell of a specific column is changed, but I don't know if that is possible. If it's not, I'll just refactor the select-case to manually call the column-specific event handlers.

```
Select Case e.Cell.Column.Key

Case "Name"
CellChanged_Name(sender, e)

Case "Title"
CellChanged_Title(sender, e)    

' ... etc ...

End Select
```

Can someone tell me if it's possible to create event handlers that fire when the cell of a specific column is changed? Or am I better off just manually calling the column specific functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handlers for the CellChange event handler will always be called when there is a change to any cell and the grid doesn't have a way to create an event handler for a specific column.  If you want you could reach out to Infragistics and recommend that they add this feature through the forums or by submitting a support request.  There are links for this each on the get help page:
http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx

Comment: Accepted because it answered my primary question of is it possible to add an event handler at the column level.

I won't be contacting Infragistics support, I'm refactoring old code. If I were writing new code, I would not use any Infragistics products.

Comment: @Walter Stabosz, I would like to hear any feedback you have on why you wouldn't use an Infragistics product.  You can email me directly ahalama@infragistics.com.

Comment: My biggest gripe with Infragistics is your documentation is terrible. See my post at http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/56337/291136.aspx . Bad documentation means debugging headaches. Which means I have to wait 3 days for a response from Infragistics support or buy a premium support contract. I switched my company over to jQuery (in our web projects) because it's free and has far superior documentation and community support, and it just works better in general.

Answer (score 2):

Please, note, I'm translating this from C# on the fly, so something could be wrong.
You need to reference the Linq namespace and then use syntax like this

in your form_load or somewhere else

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventHandler)
dictionary.Add("Name", CellChanged_Name)
dictionary.Add("Title", CellChanged_Title)
dictionary.Add("....", ....)
```

in your common CellChanged event

```
dictionary(e.Cell.Column.Key).Invoke(sender, e)
```

as a reference please look at this [Replacement for big switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381115/replacement-for-big-switch)

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I would recommend an additional change where you create a delegate that takes either the grid and cell or the cell only rather than using the existing delegate for the event args.  If you are using the sender argument, this may prevent needing to cast it in each of the handlers.

Comment: Yes this will be a very usefull improvement, sorry but I'm not very fluent with vb. Let's say that this is left out as an excercise for our readers :-)

Comment: Upvoted because it answered my secondary question of what's a good way to refactor the shitty event handler code. Also, for the record, I prefer C#; the VB.NET was not my code.